# Pattern Identification in a given dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in python, where the numbers 1 and 0 appear in different columns and in every row. I want to create an additional column that counts the number of times '1' and '0' appear consecutively in that very row. For example, lets say I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
IDs     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8

A       0     1     1      1     0     0     1     1

B       1     0     1      1     1     1     0     1

C       1     0     1      0     1     0     0     1
```

I want the output column to look like this

```
IDs     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8             output

 A      0     1     1      1     0     0     1     1               1

 B      1     0     1      1     1     1     0     1               2

 C      1     0     1      0     1     0     0     1               3
```

If someone can provider the code for this in Python 3 it would surely be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did the value in column `q1` at row `B` change to `1`?

Comment: Perhaps `df['output'] =  (np.diff(df.values, 1) == -1).sum(1)`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that. Made the necessary changes.Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eq` to check if a value is equal to `0` and `shift(-1)` to check if the next value is equal to `1`. Then we use `sum` over `axis=1`:

```
m = df.eq(1) & df.shift(-1,axis=1).eq(0)
df['Output'] = m.sum(axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  q8  Output
0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1       1
1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1       2
2   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1       3
```

---

Or we can check if the difference (`diff`) is equal to `-1` over the row axis:

```
df['Output'] = df.diff(axis=1).eq(-1).sum(axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  q8  Output
0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1       1
1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1       2
2   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1       3
```

Comment: Hi Erfan, thank you so much for this. The code works well.